# p2q_EmbedFlash using remotely hosted Flash files

Tags: javascript, object, flash, embed

I've embedded a virtual tour on [one of my client sites](http://www.castlegibson.com/locations/house/index.html).

The site is hosted by Slicehost, and as you can see the load times for the Flash movies are very slow, so my idea was to serve the swf files from Amazon S3 Europe.

To test it, I have all swfs uploaded to the same directory / bucket on Amazon, while the `index.html` and `p2q_embed_object.js` files reside on my local machine. The js file is changed to refer to the Amazon-hosted swfs. The first swf loads fine, but the others don't. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this that would allow me to serve my Flash assets from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use an iframe that calls a separate html file e.g. `video.html`. This resides in the Amazon bucket and calls the `js` and all swfs from the same bucket.